# SQL Server 2008 R2 devide by zero bug

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please tell me if I am missing something, and if I am loosing my mind

The below query produces a devide by zero error

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 1, 0

;WITH   Grouped AS (
        SELECT  ID,
                Val,
                SUM(Val) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) TotalVal
        FROM    @Test
)
, Filtered AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Grouped
        WHERE   TotalVal != 0
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Filtered
WHERE   Val / TotalVal > 0.05
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5444)

Where as the below does not produce the same error

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 1, 0

;WITH   Grouped AS (
        SELECT  ID,
                Val,
                SUM(Val) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) TotalVal
        FROM    @Test
)
, Filtered AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Grouped
        WHERE   TotalVal != 0
)
SELECT  *,
        Val / TotalVal Test
FROM    Filtered
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5445)

From looking at the estimated query plan, the first query tries to optimize the where clause as

```
[Val]/[Expr1004]>(5.000000000000000e-002) AND [Expr1004]<>(0.000000000000000e+000)
```

where I can see that the `TotalVal != 0` is after the actual `devide by TotalVal`.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way (other than using another temp table) to bypass this. I know I can do it using a

```
CASE WHEN TotalVal = 0 THEN 0 ELSE Val / TotalVal END
```

but that would defeat the purpose of the second CTE statement.

Comment: the optimizer can evaluate the cte's in any order that is valid. (just like the conditions in a where clause)

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) and vote it up.

Personally, I'm happy with the way SQL Server works, because it allows for some level of optimisation to pre-calculate (streamline) an expression rather than carry the components forward to calculate later (even it that makes sense *logically*).

As for your query, yes, the Filtered CTE is quite a non-event and should be rolled into the final query.  Writing it that way suggests that you believe CTEs are somehow processed and *cached in memory*.  That is not true - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891685/573261) to another SO question.  For an extended read of SQL Server's CTE implementation, visit [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/18/sql-server-are-the-recursive-ctes-really-set-based/).